# Unclear about the use of Bitwise AND assignment

Tags: c++, operators, bitwise-operators

Lately I was looking at some guy's C++ project and trying to figure out some of his project's working principles. I'm a bit unclear about the use of a bitwise AND assignment operator.

I can't ask him, so I thought maybe someone here can help me...

There is a "**unsigned int X = 0;**" variable, it get's allways incremented by "1" in the while loop.

```
while (...)
{
   ... some code ...
   X++;
   X &= (1024 - 1);
}
```

I don't really understand the use of "**&=**", what could be the purpose of that kind of use?

Thanks.

Comment: First things first.  Do you know what a bitwise AND operation does?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`1024 - 1` is `1023`, which is 1111111111 in binary

`X &= Y` means `X = X & Y`;

So this translates to `X = X & (binary) 1111111111`

Which will mask off everything but the ten lowest bits.

This will make X wrap around from 0 to 1023 (but isn't the same as just resetting X to zero, since it'll handle any overflow)

Comment: You explained how the operator works, but you didn't explained what's its purpose in combination of a loop and `X++`.

Comment: I was in the process of adding that detail as you commented :)

Comment: BIG thanks to ALL for the great answers! "This will make X wrap around from 0 to 1023" was what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 17):

The `&=` and the `++` together are the same as `X = (X + 1) % 1024;` but can be computed faster by the CPU.

---

`1024-1` is `11 1111 1111` in binary, so for numbers where `X < 1024`, a bitwise AND will have no effect (since any bit & 1 = the same bit). Interesting things only start to happen where X ≥ 1024, so let's consider the iteration of the loop where X starts at 1023.

```
X++;           // X= 100 0000 0000
X &= 1024-1;   //  &  11 1111 1111
               // so, X=0.
```

---

In context, then, what's happening is X increases from 0 to 1023 and then jumps back to 0. You can see this happening with much smaller numbers in the following test program. To make it easier to see, I'm using 4 (a different power of 2) instead of 1024.

```
#include <iostream>
int main () {
    unsigned int x = 0;
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ++ii) {
        x++;
        x &= (4-1);
        std::cout << "loop iteration #" << ii << ": x=" << x << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
/* expected output:
loop iteration #0: x=1 
loop iteration #1: x=2
loop iteration #2: x=3
loop iteration #3: x=0
loop iteration #4: x=1
loop iteration #5: x=2
loop iteration #6: x=3
loop iteration #7: x=0
loop iteration #8: x=1
loop iteration #9: x=2
*/
```

Comment: Most important - it's much cheaper for the CPU to perform. Unfortunately, it only works for powers of 2.

Comment: @Leeor: noted in answer.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the number is never going to get bigger than 1023.

In binary, X will be:

```
0000000000
0000000001
0000000010
0000000011
etc.
```

So when you do a bitwise AND with 1023 (1111111111), only the lowest 10 bits will remain.

Answer (score 2):

```
X &= (1024 - 1);
```

is

```
X = X & 1023
```

and remains all first `10` bits (1023 is `1111111111` binary) and set `0` the rest.

In a loop it's useful to make sure the `X` will not exceed `1023`, a simple equal code is:

```
while (...)
{
   ... some code ...
   X++;
   X = X % 1024; // more closely resembles the original intent
}
```